# Formal - Its a pity

Tags: sentence, formality

For an event, I've invited some speakers (University professors); one of them can't make it to the event and I want to say:

> Its a pity that you can't show up.

How can I say this more formally?

Thanks.

Comment: Try "That's unfortunate that you can't show up" or some similar variant with the word "unfortunate"

Comment: “Unable to attend” is probably better than “can’t show up”

Comment: Well, first of, "its" is the possessive of "it", so you're sorta saying "The pity of it that you can't show up".  Except you're saying "cant", not "can't" so you mean "The pity of it that you sanctimonious talk show up."  Or something like that.

Comment: "I'm very sorry that you won't be able to attend" is a common (in U.S. English) colloquial way to express your disappointment politely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the passive voice you can say, **"Your valuable contributions will be missed."**